# Evaluation order of TensorFlow graph nodes

Tags: tensorflow

If nodes A,B and C of a TensorFlow graph depend upon node D, then will `sess.run([A,B,C,D])`, evaluate D only once and use it to compute A,B and C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly. Please note that otherwise the order of operations is unspecified, so D will be calculated first, but if A, B, and C are not dependent on each other, their calculation order is undetermined.

But a separate `sess.run()` call ***will*** recalculate d. Consider this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

d = tf.random_uniform( shape = () )
a = d + 10.0
b = d + 20.0
c = d + 30.0

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( [ a, b, c, d ] ) )
    print( sess.run( [ a, b, c, d ] ) )
```

Outputs:

> [10.559408, 20.559408, 30.559408, 0.55940783]
>   [10.313643, 20.313644, 30.313644, 0.3136438]

As you can see, each line has the same decimals from the random generator ***d***, but the two rows are different.

Comment: Okay. So just to confirm, it will not try to evaluate D twice or more times just because it is specified separately in `sess.run()`

Comment: Yes. But a _separate_ `sess.run()` *will* recalculate. Added code sample to answer.